# Core Data update does not save and does not give any error, why?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am using a very simple piece of code to update an `NSManagedObject`, but the save does not make it to the persistent store (SQLite). There are no error messages and the logs look ok so I am a little lost.

I have scaled down the code as much as possible to try and isolate the problem as shown below.

The logs tell me that the orderNumber and status are set correctly and also the debug output of the arrays are all correct, but my simple update still fails without any error at all.

```
+ (int) synchOrderWithStatusUpdate:(NSString *)orderNumber : (int)status {
    if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSNumber *statusCheck = [NSNumber numberWithInt:status];
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrderWithStatusUpdate:ordernumber = %@, status = %d, status2 = %@", orderNumber, status, statusCheck);
    }

    synchOrderErrorCode = 0;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext;

    // *** The query for all tables uses orderNumber as selection so we set that up first for re use
    NSPredicate *predicateOrderNumber =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderNumber like[cd] %@", [NWTillHelper getCurrentOrderNumber]];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestOh = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OrderHead"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestOrp = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"OrderRow"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestTender = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tender"];

    fetchRequestOh.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;
    fetchRequestOrp.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;
    fetchRequestTender.predicate = predicateOrderNumber;

    fetchRequestOh.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequestOrp.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequestTender.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *errorOh = nil;
    NSMutableArray *orderHeads = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestOh error:&errorOh] mutableCopy];

    NSError *errorOrp = nil;
    NSArray *orderRows = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestOrp error:&errorOrp] mutableCopy];

    NSError *errorTender = nil;
    NSArray *tenderRows = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTender error:&errorTender] mutableCopy];

    if ([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrderWithStatusUpdate:orderHeadsArray: %@", [orderHeads objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrderWithStatusUpdate:orderRowsArray: %@", orderRows);
        NSLog(@"WebServices:synchOrderWithStatusUpdate:tenderRowsArray: %@", tenderRows);
    }

    // *** Set the status before upload since this dictates what will happen in backend
    // *** regardless if synch is successful or not
    NSManagedObject *orderHeadObject = nil;
    orderHeadObject = [orderHeads objectAtIndex:0];
    [orderHeadObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:status] forKey:@"status"];

    // Save the objects to persistent store
    NSError *error = Nil;
    [context save:&error];

    NSLog(@"Jongel Error = %@", error);

    if(error !=nil) {
        if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        synchOrderErrorCode = 99;
    }

    return 10101;
```

Comment: What exactly happens, which error?

Comment: As I stated in my question, there is no error, not from the fetch request and not from the save itself either, both error shows NULL, the code simply finishes without any error at all

Comment: Ah. I missed this, sorry.

Comment: Does the context have a parent context, or does it have an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?

Comment: @nils No it does not, I have a feeling the problem is with the result type being set to NSDict, and that my update assumes its an array.

Comment: @MattDouhan Good point, that's probably it.

Comment: @nils the problem is I need it to be NSDict for later on where I serialise it to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orderHeads are fetched as dictionaries. The NSManagedObjectContext will not be aware of any changes made to a dictionary. Only NSManagedObjects will be managed by the NSManagedObjectContext, hence the name ;-)

Try to fetch the orderHeadObject as an NSManagedObject as this will allow you to save the changes back into the store. If you need the dictionary for JSON serialisation: Just fetch it again as a dictionary after you have made the changes. That second fetch will be very fast since all values of the object are already cached, so CoreData won't have to reload from the database.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but how do I fetch using the ID as you suggested? I can do the second fetch with the predicate but your idea sounds faster

Comment: Sorry, I was confused... You can get objects from the context by objectID, but you won't get dictionaries this way. You can probably create a predicate with an objectID, but I don't think it's worth the effort. Your predicate is probably just as fast as the new one, minus the effort of creating a new predicate.

Comment: ok cool I will just do a second fetch then, its a very small object and this all runs in a background thread anyway when I am finished.